# Objective C syntax inside .cpp file?

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++

I'm trying to copy over some example code into my own project. The example project is iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest from the sdk. The example project contains a file called ExtAudioFileConvert.cpp. This file contains what looks like Objective-C code:

```
assert([NSThread isMainThread]);
```

The example project runs fine, but the compiler complains about the code above when I build my own project: *error: expected primary-expression before '[' token*

What's going on here? Obviously there's some way to use objective c bracket syntax in a .cpp file. What do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Why not make the file .mm? Instead of .cpp

Comment: I just changed the extension of the .cpp file to .mm, and everything compiles just fine. I'm guessing there's a project setting somewhere which will allow me to put objective c inside .cpp file.

Comment: @thyrgle, Yup, that worked. Wondering why the example project compiled and mine didn't though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the file extension to .mm for Objective-C++ instead of just .cpp for C++.

Comment: Thanks thyrgle, but my question is really how to do it with a .cpp extension.

Comment: @morgancodes: Not sure it's possible. And if it is.. I don't see why it matters.

Comment: I'm trying to import the audio conversion code in the iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest in the sdk into my own project. That project has a .cpp file with the sytax I showed above inside, so it's definitely possible. As to why it matters, I'm just trying to change as little as possible because there's QUITE a lot I don't understand in the example code. Just trying to delicately move it over in one piece if possible.

Comment: @morgancodes: Changing it to .mm will not in anyway hurt your understanding of the code. It just allows you to intermix C++ and Objective-C.

Comment: @thyrgle The iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest project is from the xCode help documentation.

Comment: http://sseyod.blogspot.com/2009/02/objective-c.html shows how to do it alternatively but really, I would just advise you use .mm.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the link. Now on to the next obstacle!

Answer (score 0):

The default build settings of iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest is ***Objective-C++***.
If you change the settings to ***According to File Type***, you will get the same error message.
So, change the file extension to .mm or change the build settings of your project.

[image: CompileSourceAS Objective-C++]